# How can i add intent-filter tag in manifest.json for crosswalk-project?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, crosswalk-runtime

i'm building a custom dialer app with ionic and cordova, i want to make my app replace the native android dialer, i was looking for that and i found that i have to add some settings in the manifest file for the app, but in crosswalk i found a manifest.json and looked at their website for editing this file but it turns out that they have just two settings, ions and permissions, but in my case i have these settings to put them in manifest file

```
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_BUTTON" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

so, is there any help add those settings please ?

Comment: I tried the solutions below (add an `intent-filter` to `AndroidManifest.xml.tpl`) and it works, showing my app as an audio player. But I don't know how to retrieve the intent's data (file to be played). I fear I'll have to use a Cordova plugin for that. In your custom dialer, did you manage to catch a phone number from another app? (gmail link, for example)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know hot to do it using manifest.json, but one quick way would be to change the Android manifest template directly. It is located at "Path/To/Crosswalk/template/AndroidManifest.xml".

```
<!-- <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />-->
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_BUTTON" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

Answer (score 0):

While sjtaheri's answer is valid, there is another way by creating a cordova plugin. In your case it would only consist of a plugin.xml with an Android section where the intent filter is added:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<plugin xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  id="com.demo.plugin.dialer"
  version="1.0.0">
    <name>DialerPlugin</name>
    <description>Blah</description>
    <license>MIT 3.0</license>
    <author>Donald Duck</author>
    <keywords>dialer, ionic, crosswalk</keywords>

    <engines>
       <engine name="cordova" version=">=3.1.0" platform="android" />
    </engines>


    <!-- android -->
    <platform name="android">
      <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest/application/activity">
        <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_BUTTON" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </platform>
```

With "ionic plugin add plugin_directory" that plugin will be added to your ionic app and the intent filter be added to the manifest.

Though it looks bit complicated it allows to add the intent filter anytime to your app, even if you had to remove and recreate the android platform for some reason. Manual changes to the Android Manifest would be removed by that otherwise.

If your app has more than one Activity this could become more difficult, though, because the filter would be added to all of them.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comment earlier, you can change the default value in the crosswalk AndroidManifest.xml template file.
I found it at:

**/Users/< *my_usr* >/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/lib/node_modules/crosswalk-app-tools/android/data/AndroidManifest.xml.tpl**

Edited it to change the "**android:minSdkVersion**" to "16" and the "android:targetSdkVersion" to "23", re-built my crosswalk app, and it worked as expected.

Good luck